# How to restore automatic backup from UbuntuOne using Dejadup?

Tags: ubuntu-one, deja-dup

I used to make an automatic backup of my files in UbuntuOne account using DejaDup. This option is no more availabe in Ubuntu 14.04. How can I get my files? They are compressed in my Ubuntu One account by DejaDup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a script to download all files of a single Ubuntu One folder through the web interface. See [blog post](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2012/02/29/downloading-all-the-files-in-an-ubuntu-one-folder/) for more details. I have tested it again and it doesn't seem to work with Firefox as stated in the post but only with Chrome. Haven't tested it but might also work with Chromium.

Here in brief what you need to do:

- Go to [blog post](http://www.kryogenix.org/days/2012/02/29/downloading-all-the-files-in-an-ubuntu-one-folder/) and store link Download U1 folder as bookmark
- Open Chrome and login to [Ubuntu One](https://one.ubuntu.com/)
- Browse to deja-dup backup folder and execute Download U1 folder bookmark

As you have all data now on your machine you can use Deja-Dup to restore it by opening Deja-Dup, press Restore... and choose Local Folder as Backup location.

You can also use duplicity to restore your files with following command

```
duplicity restore file:///path/to/downloaded/deja-dup/files /path/to/restore
```

Comment: The script to download all the files in the Ubuntu One synced folder works perfectly with Chrome and the restore of DejaDup from local folder too. I didn't try the command. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you want a replacement for the way U1 worked with Déjà Dup in not requiring a local copy of the folder, take a look at http://www.hackcraft.net/u12copy/ about getting Copy to work like U1 did. Toward the end I cover getting Déjà Dup to write to it over a mount so you don't need to have a local folder of the gpg files.

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu One was [announced to be discontinued](http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/) (file-sync-cloud and mp3 store at least), but it isn't completely discontinued - [see this page](http://www.ubuntu.com/tablet/app-ecosystem) where they advertise "cloud-syncing database api", and not just files.

You should download all your data from U1 while you can. :( Hopefully they're making something even better soon.

Comment: I can't simply download my files because I used the app DejaDup (that was greatly integrated with UbuntuOne) to make my backup. So in my Ubuntu one account I have a synced folder full of sigtar.gz and difftar.gz. How can I get my files throught these compressed files?